# Facebook Tab and AKAMAI Hosted content

Tags: facebook, akamai

We are facing the following issue. We are building a Facebook Tab page, and the `SSL` `URL`, is through AKAMAI (something like: `https://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/{PATH}`). The Non Secure page tab, is served through a normal `URL` (eg. `http://ourapp.com`)
Both `URL`s are properly configured and resolved by Facebook (tested through Linter), but, when we open the page tab, we get:

```
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://a248.e.akamai.net/" on this server.
```

It seems, that Facebook, POSTs to the secure `URL`, without the full `URL`, just the domain part.
the thing is getting weirder, if we append an image to the app settings.
when we put:

```
Non Secure Tab: http://ourdomain.com/image1.jpg
Secure Tab: https://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/{PATH}/image1.jpg
```

Then the access denied is like this:

```
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access `http://a248.e.akamai.net/image1.jpg on this server.
```

Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For Access Denied issues, you usually get a error reference number too. Say something like #18.e.12sd.sdffsdf so on.. If you translate this error reference code in Akamai diagnostics feature, you will be able to see more details on why the request is denied. And i am not sure why are you requesting http://a248.e.akamai.net/image1.jpg in first place ? It should be your application domain followed by image1.jpg. DNS will then resolve your domain to Akamai domain which in turn will resolve to one of the akamai edge servers ip.